# node.js: merge 2 images side by side and save it back

Tags: image, node.js

My **thumbnail** images are stored in amazon s3. I want to **merge 2 images** from them into a separate side by side image and **store it back in s3** (in a different bucket).
I have hundreds of images there and there is a possibility of adding more images everyday.
So I want to do this in a separate process whenever new images are available in the s3 bucket or whenever new values are inserted into database.
I know there are imagemagic and node-canvas.
What is the best practice here, well, in node.js.

Comment: Best practices for what?  It sounds like you know what you need to do.  What specific programming problem are you facing?

Comment: OK, sorry for the confusion. intent of the question was to know, if my approach was fine, or, if there are any better approaches. Also wanted to know if there are any other modules available that can do the job better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-canvas` is ought to be drawing, on the other-hand `imagemagick` is actually an indpendent and dedicated image operations library like resizing, cropiing, montaging, advanced operations like fourier transform. So it's better to use `imagemagick`

Comment: Soory, I felt that node-canvas would be appropriate. get the 2 images, draw them side by side in the canvas context and save it back. Why are you saying imagemagick ? Do you have any sample code ?

Comment: Imagemagick is a large library that can do many operations, I think it will be faster, but no evidence, I did not try. It spawns a process. For example combining two images is just executing "convert file1.jpg file2.jpg  +append -quality 75 'widerfile.jpg'" and its easy to use in nodejs "convert(args, callback(err, stdout, stderr))"